# Does not openpyxl.styles have a Style anymore in v2.4.0?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I just upgraded `openpyxl` to version `2.4.0` and this code that worked fine in previous versions, doesn't work anymore:

```
style = openpyxl.styles.Style(**style_kwargs)
```

Openpyxl says that it doesn't have a `Style` attribute:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Style'
```

How does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Style` class was deprecated several versions ago and has been removed.

Comment: what about a link about how to migrate, for the shake of completeness