# Cannot import import Style from openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've been able to import openpyxl and have succeeded in changing the font color of some of the characters but when I write the following line:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Style
```

I get an error saying that it cannot import Style.  I've also tried lowercasing style.  I find this strange because the following work just fine:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font
from openpyxl.styles import Fill, Color
```

Comment: Always use the correct documentation for the version you're using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if you are basing this effort on a Tutorial or not, but `Style` is not an option available in `openpyxl.styles` for `openpyxl` version 2.4.8.

Here I import openpyxl.styles and then examine all the options that are available using the `dir()` function.

As you note, items like `Font`, `PatternFill`, etc are present, but `Style` is not.

```
In [2]: import openpyxl.styles as ops

In [3]: dir(ops)
Out[3]:
['Alignment',
 'Border',
 'Color',
 'DEFAULT_FONT',
 'Fill',
 'Font',
 'GradientFill',
 'NamedStyle',
 'NumberFormatDescriptor',
 'PatternFill',
 'Protection',
 'Side',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'absolute_import',
 'alignment',
 'borders',
 'builtins',
 'cell_style',
 'colors',
 'differential',
 'fills',
 'fonts',
 'is_builtin',
 'is_date_format',
 'named_styles',
 'numbers',
 'protection',
 'proxy',
 'styleable',
 'stylesheet',
 'table']
```

This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677426/does-not-openpyxl-styles-have-a-style-anymore-in-v2-4-0) indicates that `Style` was deprecated:

This [section of the openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) has some guidance on using styles. It is likely that what you are trying to achieve is described therein.

Comment: isn't that a bit crazy to do `import openpyxl.styles as os` while you have the built-in `os` Python module?  :)

Comment: Link to openpyxl documentation changed: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html